# Division Lemma Mathematical insight

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x$ be an integer.

a) Prove that there exists $r \in \{0,\ldots,m-1\}$ such that $x\equiv r \mod m$.
(use the division lemma)

b) Prove that the $r$ is unique

Comment: Take $m$ as your divisor, dividing it into $x$; what does the division lemma tell you? If you just write that down correctly, you’ve done (a).

Answer (score 1):

$1$. Define the set
$$S = \{y \in \mathbb{N}: y = x-m\cdot k \text{ where }k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
$2$. Show that $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $S$ is non-empty.

$3$. Make use of the well-ordering principle and choose the smallest non-negative element in this set, say $r$.

$4$. Show that $r \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$. (Argue this by contradiction)